# Excel Table will not keep TEXT formatting when pasting in from VBA variant

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm pasting into an excel table with variant data from vba. However - I need the data to be exactly as it shows in VBA - so for instance data in column A needs to be "0000" but whenever I paste it in excel re-formats to general.

It looks like the formatting might be stuck in the variant, but I've go no idea how to set variant to be exact text.

The following is how I'm pasting in. Any help is appreciated :)

```
    tConverted.DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "@"

'*This line adds the data from the variant array into the table
    tConverted.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange(rowAdd.Index).Resize(UBound(vConverted), tConverted.ListColumns.Count).Value = vConverted

'*This section deletes any blank rows that may have been created by forgetting to select data
    Do While tConverted.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Value = ""
        If tConverted.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Value = "" Then
            tConverted.DataBodyRange.Rows(1).Delete
        End If
    Loop

MsgBox "Test", vbOKOnly
```

Comment: Have you tried applying the `.NumberFormat = "@"` after you've pasted the value into the cell?  for example
 
`With tConverted.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange(rowAdd.Index).Resize(UBound(vConverted), tConverted.ListColumns.Count)
    .Value = vConverted
    .NumberFormat = "@"
End With`

Comment: Yes, because of how this paste works it posts the entire variant to the table at once - it would paste it in as the  date formats and stuff like that then would convert everything to text after the fact so dates would then show as 42986 rather than 09/08/2017

Comment: so only format the specific *list column* you need to be "0000" as that. Or if you have a column with mixed data types, you can loop through each cell and check if its date otherwise format as "0000"

Comment: @ScottHoltzman How do I format the column to add leading zeroes? So, for instance, one section might have "30" or "700" and I need it to show "0030" or "0700"

Comment: @RyanWilliamNoon `tConverted.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "0000"`

Comment: That worked! You rock! @ScottHoltzman